# ubuntu 18.04 tourn off the screen but dosn't shutting down since the last update

Tags: upgrade, shutdown, freeze, radeon, amd-ryzen

When I try to shut it down, I click on power off, it turn off the screen and freeze, I am forced to push and hold the power button to turn it off. And it even get a bit hatter than it was before shutting down started.

I have tried `alt + F2` and `ctrl + alt + Esc` and `ctrl + alt + F2` and `ctrl + alt + F2` (because I don't remember the good combination) and it didn't open the terminal. I have tried to turn it off from the terminal, the result was the same.
I tried to update and upgrade the pc again hoping that the bug will be fixed in the updated version and since than, when I turn on the pc, it shows me the message that the pc needs to be restarted in order to finish the updating but as it is not possible to restart it correctly, is continues to show me that message.

It seems like it started when I updated. But I am not sure. It was about the same time when I installed 2 or 3 things to customize my dock panel.

HP pavilion |
Ryzen 5 |
Radeon vega graphics

Edited: unfortunately I noticed your the comment below too late.The model is 15-cw1011nf. And here's the results of the asked commands

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact model HP Pavilion.

Answer (score 0):

with ryzen , also your screen might fail or system goes to wrong cstate, this can be a funny search

- see [Gentoo WIKI](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Ryzen) for specific command lines and sleep modes to prevent
- the system might still react to the [Magic SysRQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) combination when the graphic freezes .. suggested order:
- - **u** (Umount)
- - **s** (Sync)
- - **b** (reBoot)

there is a "similar" thread here where switching away from gnome is suggested:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/517543/ubuntu-18-04-amd-ryzen-why-random-freeze

---

Comment: Thank you fot your answer. I will try the magic SysRQ the next time I shut it down but I would like to find a permanent solution and not just cure the symptom.

Comment: sysrq is just for safety of your file system , read about cstates and maybe switch to metacity ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/517543/ubuntu-18-04-amd-ryzen-why-random-freeze ) ,

Comment: I am sorry I have formulated my question in a vary bad way, actually it freeze only when i try to shut it down. When I click on power off it starts shutting down, it tourn off the screen but then it stay like this without shutting down, and it even get a bit hatter than it was before shutting down started. Ill fo edit my question.

Comment: ah okay, you might  see this in systemd journal or by changing directly to console when shutting down ( if there is a splash  press `ESC` )  , there might be (systemd)-daemons or network mounts waiting 4ever ...  normally the system shows messages on tty1 during shutdown ,  systemd would say something like "waiting for SERVICE" ...

Comment: There was no cursor or any thing, the screen was off completely. It is an ips screen so you can see when it's off and it was off.

Answer (score 0):

After an other update and a forceful shutdown it started to work normally. Unfortunately I didn't understood the reason of the problem.